# unable to download updates failed to refresh cache

Tags: software-center, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 19.10 and I am getting this message: `Unable to download updates - failed to refresh cache: w: ignoring file 'wir' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension`.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

---

```
$ ls -1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
brave-browser-beta.list
brave-browser-beta.list.save
brave-browser-release.list
brave-browser-release.list.save
brave.list
brave.list.save
windscribe-repo.list
windscribe-repo.list.save
wir
```

Comment: Please add output of `ls -1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to the question.

Comment: Brave-browser-beta.list

Comment: brave-browser-beta.list
brave-browser-beta.list.save
brave-browser-release.list
brave-browser-release.list.save
brave.list
brave.list.save
windscribe-repo.list
windscribe-repo.list.save
wir

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove problematic "sources" list file with

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wir
```

and then update package lists with

```
sudo apt update
```